# wxWidgets defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts problem

Tags: user-interface, frameworks, wxwidgets

So, I have a small project with a very simple code. All it really does is create a wxFrame the following way:

```
wxFrame(NULL, -1, title, wxPoint(-1, -1), wxSize(380, 220))
```

There is no compiling problem to any of my code whatsoever. The problem occures when I do this line:

```
IMPLEMENT_APP(App);
```

App is:

```
class App: public wxApp
```

So, when I do that and I hit compile, I  have the following errors:

```
1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
1>CApp.obj : warning LNK4248: unresolved typeref token (01000019) for 'wxVideoMode'; image may not run
1>CLoadingFrame.obj : warning LNK4248: unresolved typeref token (01000019) for 'wxToolTip'; image may not run
1>CLoadingFrame.obj : warning LNK4248: unresolved typeref token (0100001A) for 'wxDropTarget'; image may not run
1>CLoadingFrame.obj : error LNK2020: unresolved token (0A000DB2) "int g_isPainting" (?g_isPainting@@3HA)
1>CApp.obj : error LNK2020: unresolved token (0A000DBE) "int g_isPainting" (?g_isPainting@@3HA)
1>CLoadingFrame.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000DB4) "void __cdecl wxOnAssert(char const *,int,char const *,char const *,char const *)" (?wxOnAssert@@$$FYAXPBDH000@Z) referenced in function "protected: void __thiscall wxShadowObjectFields_wxImplementation_HashTable::ResizeTable(unsigned int)" (?ResizeTable@wxShadowObjectFields_wxImplementation_HashTable@@$$FIAEXI@Z)
1>CApp.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000DC0) "void __cdecl wxOnAssert(char const *,int,char const *,char const *,char const *)" (?wxOnAssert@@$$FYAXPBDH000@Z) referenced in function "protected: void const * __thiscall wxVectorBase::GetItem(unsigned int)const " (?GetItem@wxVectorBase@@$$FIBEPBXI@Z)
1>CApp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl wxOnAssert(char const *,int,char const *,char const *,char const *)" (?wxOnAssert@@$$FYAXPBDH000@Z) referenced in function "protected: void const * __thiscall wxVectorBase::GetItem(unsigned int)const " (?GetItem@wxVectorBase@@$$FIBEPBXI@Z)
1>CLoadingFrame.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl wxOnAssert(char const *,int,char const *,char const *,char const *)" (?wxOnAssert@@$$FYAXPBDH000@Z)
1>CApp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "int g_isPainting" (?g_isPainting@@3HA)
1>CLoadingFrame.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "int g_isPainting" (?g_isPainting@@3HA)
1>CApp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall wxAppConsole::OnAssertFailure(char const *,int,char const *,char const *,char const *)" (?OnAssertFailure@wxAppConsole@@UAEXPBDH000@Z)
1>CApp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall wxAppConsole::OnAssert(char const *,int,char const *,char const *)" (?OnAssert@wxAppConsole@@UAEXPBDH00@Z)
1>D:\WickedLauncher\WickedLauncherv2\Debug\WickedLauncherv2.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 8 unresolved externals
```

I would appreciate any help!

Regards.

Comment: It looks like you are using C++ and Visual Studio.  Is that correct?  Are you doing a debug or release build?  Have you checked that all the wxWidgets libraries match ( are debug or release )?  Are you saying that if you comment out IMPLEMENT_APP(App); your application links successfully?

Answer (score 0):

where is defined g_isPainting ?

Did you add the right library to the linker for wxAppConsole ?

Comment: I do not define g_isPainting so it must be within the wxWidgets. And what exactly do you mean by "added the right library to the linker". I configured everything as I was told by the documentation. I already compiled stuff which worked fine.